# Nextjs does not display elements

Tags: html, css, next.js

I own a [website](https://satindars-den.cf) and when i want to make a contact section for it. I am using the following code

```html
      <section className={styles.contact}>
        <p>Test</p>
      </section>
```

I which I have made a import statement to import a style sheet like so `import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'`
In my style sheet, i used the following code for the contact property

```css
.contact {
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
```

with my container having the size of 300vh

```css
.container {
  height: 300vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But when i check it, I do not see the `<p>test</p>`
[image: What happens]

Any idea why and how I can fix it?

Google and stack overflow don't seem to have any information on this

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have seen is that as you are giving fix height to `.container` your contact section overflowing and thus not showing. remove fix `height: 300vh` from `.container` and you will see `Test`. Then style on different way. Or you can also remove `overflow: hidden` so that overflowing element become visible on scroll.

Comment: Just tried you answer, did not change anything. The website still looks the same like it did before.

Comment: I have just uncheck `height: 300vh` from browser console and it's showing up. How did you tried?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I tried it again and it worked. No idea what happened before haha.

Answer (score 1):

Change the height of your `.container` height to `height:100vh`. The viewport height is represented by vh. 300vh equals 300% of the current viewport height. That is, if your current viewport height is 800 pixels , then viewport height will be 800*3 = 2400 pixels.and also because of overflow:hidden outside of your content doesn't show up, Overflowing content indicates that content beyond your viewport height has been hidden. So you can change your height to `height:100vh`. That will solve your problem.